# logstash 2.3.3 multiline filter not working with multiple workers

Tags: java, logstash, jruby, elastic-stack

I have started logstash with multiple workers > 16.

I have multiline messages like java exceptions/java traces and want to merge them into a single event. Earlier, It was working as expected but after upgrading my ELK stack it's breaking :-(

my logstash filter :

```
filter {
  multiline {

    pattern => "(^[a-zA-Z.]+(?:Error|Exception): .+)|(^\s+at .+)|(^\s+... \d+ more)|(^\s*Caused by:.+)"
    what => "previous"
  }
}
```

logstash logs :

```
:message=>"Warning: Manual override - there are filters that might not work with multiple worker threads", :worker_threads=>16, :filters=>["multiline"], :level=>:warn}
Exception in pipelineworker, the pipeline stopped processing new events, please check your filter configuration and restart Logstash.
```

Comment: Hi @MitterSinghThakur if the answer has solved your question please consider accepting it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. But there is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have upgraded from Logstash version 1.5, it is expected.
In the version 2.0 was introduced the worker threads, but since the multiline filter is not thread-safe, it prevents using more than one worker thread.

So you'll have to either :

- Use the [multiline codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.3/plugins-codecs-multiline.html).
  For example to join java exception stacktrace :

  ```
  input {
    stdin {
      codec => multiline {
        pattern => "(^.+Exception: .+)|(^\s+at .+)|(^\s+... \d+ more)|(^\s*Caused by:.+)"
        what => "previous"
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Do the multiline operation on your shipper (both beaver and filebeat can be configured to do it)
- Use only one worker thread (in that case you can use multiple instances of Logstash to use all your CPU cores, but keep in mind that the multiline filter will be eventually removed).

Comment: You can take a look to this for more information: [elastic blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-moving-away-from-node-protocol-and-multiline-filter), [github issue](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/4386)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am using logstash-forwarder as a shipper, It will be great if you can put some lite on that. it would be great if you can share config example server & client side. I need to ship java exceptions as well as other logs from all app servers to the logstash server using logstash forwarder, example logs : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.myproject.Book.getTitle(Book.java:16)
        at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookTitles(Author.java:25)
        at com.example.myproject.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:14)

Comment: I don't know for configuration of logstash-forwarder. I have updated my answer for the multiline codec, but you'll have to check if it works as intended for your use case. The regex comes from [here](https://gist.github.com/smougenot/3182192).

Comment: it's working but not as expected. when there are numbers of messages/logs, for some reason, it stops working. for now, on a single box, I have run two instances of logstash. on one, I have configured 16 workers & on the other one, I have only 1 worker (I am pushing multi-line messages/logs here). I know this is not permanent solution but It's working for me :)